# Submitting cookie in dynamic form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am making a dynamic form and submitting it, when user clicks a href tag.

Here is the code

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#logout").click(function () {
          var form = document.createElement('form');
          form.setAttribute('action', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout/user');
          form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
          document.body.appendChild(form);
          form.submit();
        });

      });

    </script>
```

Issue is that, i have to also submit a cookie which was previously set when user logged in my application. Currently at the back end i am not getting the cookie.

How to submit the cookie as well.

Comment: You don’t “submit” cookies explicitly, the browser does that for you. If you are not getting a cookie, then most likely you did not have one set on the client side in the first place - or it is not valid for the path you are sending your form to.

Comment: @CBroe yes you are correct. I checked through the chrome setting and my cookie is set at path /sayd/login and i am trying it to access it at my controller which is exposed at path /sayd/logout. So how should i handle this?

Comment: You need to specify the path as `/sayd/` when setting the cookie.

Comment: @CBroe yes it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can then do:

$.cookie("test", 1);
To delete:

$.removeCookie("test");
Additionally, to set a timeout of a certain number of days (10 here) on the cookie:

$.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10 });
If the expires option is omitted, then the cookie becomes a session cookie, and is deleted when the browser exits.

To cover all the options:

$.cookie("test", 1, {
   expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days

   path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                           //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

   domain  : 'jquery.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                           //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

   secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                           //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                           //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```